# Printing using Adobe Reader > Fatal Error: Acrobat failed to connect to a DDE Server

Tags: vb.net, adobe, dde

Tried to print using Adobe Reader but am getting this message: Fatal Error: Acrobat failed to connect to a DDE Server

```
Dim AcroRd32ExePath As String = GetAcroRdPath()
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
startInfo.FileName = AcroRd32ExePath
startInfo.Arguments = String.Format(" /s /o /h /t ""{0}"" ""{1}""", fileName, PrinterName2)
startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Process.Start(startInfo)

'CAUTION: Adobe Reader silently rejects the print job if the printer name doesn't match case exactly

'The following switches are available:
'/n - Launch a new instance of Reader even if one is already open
'/s - Don't show the splash screen
'/o - Don't show the open file dialog
'/h - Open as a minimized window
'/p <filename> - Open and go straight to the print dialog
'/t <filename> <printername> <drivername> <portname> - Print the file the specified printer.
'http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a user that had both Adobe Acrobat Standard and Adobe Reader. Turns out they had never actually opened the Reader before. All I had to do was open Reader manually and accept the license terms. Works fine!